# In ASP, creating dynamic textboxes and assign value to them?

Tags: asp.net, database

I am working with a webpage and I will connect the data i have to a data base. so my question how can I create different number of labelsand assigning values or data to them and not loss them? I working on a web page and i have placeholders for the new labels but i have no idea how to keep them there and assign value to them in order to save them in the database.and the following is part of my code and i put placeholder to create more labels in the execution time.

```
<tr> 
<td style="text-align:right"><b><br /><br />
   <asp:Label ID="lblAudioLabel" runat="server">Audio:</asp:Label>
   <br /><br /></b>
</td> 
<td><br /><br />
   <asp:Label ID="lblPrimary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   <br />
   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolderAudio" runat="server" /><br />
</td> 
</tr>
```

The numbers I need to add will vary every time. So, Im thinking to add a new number every time that i have more than one number in the placeHolder. Im new to ASP so any help will a lot for me.

Comment: Just so I understand: You want to create a dynamic number of labels that you put in `placeHolderAudio`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have a database that i want to retrieve data from it. the data will be showing on the webpage using labels. the number of labels will be different. It depends on how many fields do i have for this particular. for example, the column numbers will be vary so of them has 2 numbers and some other have totally different numbers of fields.

Comment: You mentioned in your original question that you want to save the data back to the DB. Yet, you are using the `Label` control. The `Label` control is not editable by users. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well I am doing two web pages one to write to it which is im ganna use text box and to display them im going to use labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a built-in ASP.NET data-binding control rather than the placeholder method.

Here is a good tutorial explaining the basics of databinding in ASP.NET. It is older, from 2004, but still very applicable.

[Mastering ASP.NET DataBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8659/Mastering-ASP-NET-DataBinding)

HTH

Comment: Thank you Shai, I will check this link out.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any specific questions. We can go to a chat room. Also, if this answer helped, you can click the up arrow to give me some Stack Overflow love :) (shameless, i know)

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is basically saving the textbox values each time and then adding new values with textbox, if i have proper understanding of your requirement then what you can do is to create a list of those values from textbox and ad it to view state and next time when the page posts back you can again create new textboxses and populate values in them by fetching them view state.